# jQuery transition on class change and transition delay on paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a section using codepen that can be visited from here: [Click Here](http://codepen.io/immad-hamid/pen/BWqLvB)

If you see my code, you will see that I am repeating the same thing every time now want to improve my JS so that it's less and perform well. Please advice what can be done in order to improve this code.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
IMMAD

// Here is the Js

```
$(".div1").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        console.log('hello');
        $('.div2, .div3').addClass('widthlow');
        $('.div1').addClass('widthmax');
        $(".widthmax p").addClass('opacity');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.div2, .div3').removeClass('widthlow');
        $('.div1').removeClass('widthmax');
        $('.div1 p').removeClass('opacity');
    }
});

$(".div2").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        console.log('hello');
        $('.div1, .div3').addClass('widthlow');
        $('.div2').addClass('widthmax');
        $('.smoky').addClass('opacity');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.div1, .div3').removeClass('widthlow');
        $('.div2').removeClass('widthmax');
        $('.smoky').removeClass('opacity');
    }
});

$(".div3").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        console.log('hello');
        $('.div1, .div2').addClass('widthlow');
        $('.div3').addClass('widthmax');
        $('.smoky').addClass('opacity');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.div1, .div2').removeClass('widthlow');
        $('.div3').removeClass('widthmax');
        $('.smoky').removeClass('opacity');
    }
});
```

Comment: Define "*better*," and which 'tag' are you talking about wanting to load?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am talking about the js and css(in case if it can help) I had to paste this code here because when I was only submitting the the codepen link, I was having a validation error which said you have to add the code in your codepen.

Comment: I don't know why people are un-voting my question.
I have made something myself and I am not asking to re-write anything, what I am trying to ask is if anyone could help me in refining things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a little opacity animation and changed transitions to `ease-in-out` here. Looks a little better? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZaoZx

Comment: I found a solution for doing this, thanks for the answer and your effort.
I have updated my codepen. Now I just want to improve the js code so that it is not repetitive.

Comment: I added a `.panel` class and made the function a little more reusable. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvQNNo